# How to authenticate user with an auth token from api

Tags: android

I'm trying to authenticate users and grant them a token with an api from https://www.themoviedb.org/ . When the user opens the app and clicks sign in button, I want a browser activity to open and display the sign in page for https://www.themoviedb.org/ and after signing in or creating account to get a token. I already have an api key from https://www.themoviedb.org/.

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to get a tutorial for what I want.

Comment: At the top right of the page there is API link.Click the link and there is documentation

Comment: Depending on the language you're using, this page shows you some API to start with : https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/wrappers-libraries

Comment: Check this link https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details

Comment: Thanks i'll try it.